# Java module system unable to discover Gradle dependency: gdx (libgdx)

Tags: java, gradle, libgdx, java-platform-module-system

I am building a project with LibGDX using Java Module System (JPMS) from Java 9, unfortunately JPMS is unable locate the gdx dependency that I am retrieving in my build.gradle file from:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.badlogicgames.gdx/gdx/1.11.0

repositories:

```
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
```

module specific dependencies:

```
project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"
    dependencies {
        implementation project(':common')
        implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
    }
}
```

module-info.java file

```
module core {
    exports sdu.dk.group.one;
    requires common;
    requires gdx;
}
```

The module is able to find the `implementation project(':common')` which means Gradle is able to discover dependency sources and Java is able to infer the dependencies of the modules correctly to them.
Additional information:

## Steps taken to solve this issue:

1. Using different keywords to store the dependency differently at compile/run-time:

```
implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
runtime "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
compileOnly "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
```

I have also attempted the official dependency declaration from: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.badlogicgames.gdx/gdx/1.11.0#gradle

```
implementation group: 'com.badlogicgames.gdx', name: 'gdx', version: '1.11.0'
```

All resulting in the same error: "error: module not found: gdx \n requires gdx;"

I have consulted the official documentation from Gradle about Java 9 modules:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_java_modules_multi_project.html
However, this does not seem to be related to my issue since my local dependencies are working as expected i.e. (':common')

I have also tried different plugins for Gradle such as:

```
apply plugin: "java"
apply plugin: "java-library"
```

I've spent the majority of the day trying to solve this issue so any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you for the time spent on reading this post.

update:
Disregarding the project structure that Gradle Assumes (src:directory/main:module/java:sources-root) https://i.stack.imgur.com/ht07H.jpg will make the JPSM discover the gdx dependency, however this is overwritten when reloading Gradle.

Comment: That library does no have a module descriptor or a stable module name.

Comment: Is it possible to add a module descriptor to the library?

Comment: Another observation I have done is that, my modules can discover the "gdx" dependency if I don't have nested modules. https://imgur.com/8xXtzUM : it does seem that Gradle assumes that main must be a module.